# How can I programmatically click on this web page button

Tags: json, google-chrome, validation, browser, delphi-2007

I have a Delphi 2007 application that generates a lump of JSON.  In order the validate the JSON quickly I was submitting it via the URL to JSONLint.com (as here: https://jsonlint.com/?json=%7B%22hello%22:%20%22world%22%7D).  The amount of JSON you can submit this way is limited however, so I resorted to copying the JSON to the clipboard and then invoking [JSONLint.com](https://JSONLint.com), which loads the validation page and leaves focus in the memo where the text to be validated is submitted.  That just left the manual steps of:

- `Ctrl-V` to paste the JSON into the memo.
- Click on the `Submit JSON` button.

I want to automate these last 2 steps.  I am using `SendInput ()` to send a Ctrl-V to the memo, but I can't see how to move focus to the `Submit JSON` button.  Once focus is in the memo, the only way I can find to move it elsewhere is `Ctrl-L` to move focus to the address bar, then successive tabs to move it to the next tab-stoppable element.  Once we tab into the memo however successive tabs are just entered into the memo text.  So my question:

How can I "click" on a particular element on a browser web page?

```
<div class="validate">
  <button type="submit" data-ga="validate">Validate JSON</button>
  ...
</div>
```

I don't need it to be browser-agnostic (using Chrome as the default browser).

Comment: I would suggest using an embedable browser directly in your app, and then use the browser's own APIs to manipulate the HTML DOM directly. Then you would be able to set the Memo's text and click the submit button, without involving the clipboard or the keyboard at all.

Comment: Or better, just use a validating JSON library directly in your code. Or at least another JSON validation site that supports the amount of JSON you need to submit via URL or POST request.

Comment: Thanks, Remy.  I've been experimenting further, and discovered that `Shift-Tab` performs the opposite of `Tab` - i.e it moves to the previous element.  So I can do what I need by: `Ctrl-V` to paste the JSON in.  `Ctrl-L` to move focus to the address bar.  `Shift-Tab` to tab to the last element on the page. `Shift-Tab` 14 (!) more times to get to the `Submit JSON` button. `Enter` to submit the JSON.  Horribly fragile but it works.  I may look at a validation library.

Comment: Yes, what you describe is horribly fragile, and very likely to break if the site's UI is every changed, or even if the browser simply doesn't behave as expected.

Comment: If you select the - fragile - solution to embed a WebBrowser in a Delphi program and automate it, an old blog article I wrote will interest you: http://francois-piette.blogspot.com/2013/01/internet-explorer-automation-part-1.html

Comment: I was referring to simulating keyboard input to an external browser as being "horribly fragile". Automating an embeded browser is much less fragile (using the HTML DOM is accurate), but it is still not error-proof, if the site UI (and thus the DOM) ever changes, requiring a code update to compensate